# How to get JSON sub array data from array with equal option and value with Mustache.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache

I am trying to work with Mustache.js that is really helping.

I am stuck on getting array with specific option and value.

My JSON is looking like that:

```
    {
    "departments": [
        {
            "department": [
                {
                    "id": 114,
                    "deptName": "Department 1",
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "id": 127,
                            "catName": "Category Name",
                            "subCategory": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 115,
                            "catName": "Category Name",
                            "subCategory": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "department": [
                {
                    "id": 123,
                    "deptName": "Department 2",
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "id": 126,
                            "catName": "Category Name",
                            "subCategory": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 124,
                            "catName": "Category Name",
                            "subCategory": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To get main department names it is easy as:

JS:

```
$.ajax({

            url: 'link_to_json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var template = $('#pageHomeTpl').html();
                var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                $('#category-list').html(html);
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="category-list">
                <script id="pageHomeTpl" type="text/template">
                    {{#departments}}
                    {{#department}}
                    <li><a href="{{id}}">{{deptName}}</a></li>
                    {{/department}}
                    {{/departments}}
                  </script>
                </ul>
```

But now I need to somehow get categories ("category:") from department with specific ID, for example "id": 114.

Any help, please.

Comment: You mean in the `success` callback, you need to filter the categories with specific ID?

Comment: Yes, on success I need to be able to have only department with id 114 subcategories.

Comment: Why have you designed the department inside departments as an array ? Should it not be an object instead of array ?

Comment: Problem is that I cant change JSON, have to work with what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in these lines, with jQuery `map()` and `grep()`

```
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
var filtereddata = {"departments" : []}; 
var filtereddept= {};
filtereddept.department= $.map(data.departments, function(alldept,indx){
    return $.grep(alldept.department, function(deptobj,indx){
        return deptobj.id==114;
    });
});
filtereddata.departments[0]=filtereddept;
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtereddata));
```

The template to iterate the category of departments:

```
   <script id="pageHomeTpl" type="text/template">
                    {{#departments}}
                    {{#department}}
                    <li><a href="{{id}}">{{deptName}}</a></li>
                     {{#category}}
                     <ul>
                    <li><a href="{{id}}">{{catName}}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    {{/category}}
                    {{/department}}
                    {{/departments}}
      </script>
```

Comment: Thanks @AhamedMustafaM, this looks logical and I can get 1 department json now, that is really good. But now I am facing the problem that mustache.js don't show any errors and not taking category subarrays as well. Hm...

Comment: I tried with the resulting `filtereddata` in your template. I didn't get any error.Let me update my answer with my template.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have. Maybe its something with the JSON after your code. I will be very thankful if you can take a look, I am so stuck on that. The JS, Template and JSON I have - http://cloud.ignatynikulin.com/0b3l39121l1c3s3x0t1C in TXT file. I also notice that JSON before search is wrapped in ?() to prevent cross-domain error in Webkit.

Comment: Instead of passing stringified-JSON, pass the actual JSON to the Mustache. Remove line `var oneCategoryJSON = JSON.stringify(filtereddata);`.                              
Change `var html = Mustache.to_html(template, oneCategoryJSON);` to `var html = Mustache.to_html(template, filtereddata);`.

Comment: Why, why! I dont get that, I tried that before 2 hrs ago, exact same thing and it didn't work. And now it's working fine. Must be cache... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't test it but it seems to be work...

```
...
success: function(data) {
    var template = $('#pageHomeTpl').html();
    var item = data.departments
    for(key in item){
        if(key == 'id' && item[key] == 114 ){
            var html = Mustache.to_html(template, item);
        }
    }
    $('#category-list').html(html);
}
...
```

with FOR .. IN statement you can cycle in your object or array take look at this link
[js_loop_for_in](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp)